# Preview image before upload with Carrierwave

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, html, carrierwave

I have a form where user can create new pictures. I've successfully done it with Carrierwave. I was wondering is it possible to preview selected image in browser before upload? I've found some try outs with javascript but didn't work for me.

This is the code for image upload with CARRIERWAVE:

```
<%= form_for @photo, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>

  <%= f.file_field :image %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Save Photo" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

My goal is to have one small thumbnail of image so user can see it before upload. I am guessing I can't use Rails here because it could be only for server side...

Any ideas? :)

Comment: There are some ways but not cross-browser because they use HTML5's File API (see http://kellishaver.tumblr.com/post/21428272282/using-the-file-api-to-preview-images-before-uploading)

Comment: @bcd - Tnx! That works!

Answer (score 4):

If you are using bootstrap 3 there is an awesome extension for it here 
http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/javascript/#fileinput

Answer (score 0):

I've found a lot of success in using Transloadit: https://transloadit.com/ and handing that off to Carrierwave on the success call. There is also a transloadit gem that makes things even easier: https://github.com/transloadit/rails-sdk. Using this method will give you a preview, modal, loading bar, and a bunch of other options you can turn on or off for a great user experience. It has the same options for resizing or cropping that carrierwave does, or you can hand it off to carrierwave to do it for you. Your jquery callback to your controller might look something like:

updateAttachment: function(fileName, attachmentType) {
      var self = this;

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "PUT",
    url: <your update url>,
    data: {
      attachment: {
        file: fileName
      }
    },
    success: function() {
      location = self.windowLocation();
    },
    error: function() {
      self.showError("Error uploading file.");
      location = self.windowLocation();
    }
  });
}
```